# JavaFX AnchorPane maxHeight ignored with clipped Circle

Tags: javafx, height, clip

I have an AnchorPane which contains a clipped circle. I set a maximum height to the anchorpane, so that if the circle's y position is high, the circle won't be displayed. The problem is that when the circle goes to the lower part of the anchorpane, it increases it's height. This should not be happening.

This happens even before the clipped element reaches the lower part of the anchorpane. Once the "invisible" part of the circle reaches the lower part, it starts increasing it's height.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod;
import javafx.scene.paint.RadialGradient;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Init extends Application {

    private AnchorPane canvasContainer;

    private AnchorPane mainPane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        canvasContainer = new AnchorPane();
        mainPane = new AnchorPane();

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 800, 700);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        canvasContainer.setPrefWidth(600.0d);
        canvasContainer.setPrefHeight(500.0d);

        //IGNORED
        canvasContainer.setMaxHeight(canvasContainer.getPrefHeight());

        canvasContainer.setLayoutX(14.0d);
        canvasContainer.setLayoutY(14.0d);

        canvasContainer.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 1 1 1 1;");

        RadialGradient gradient = new RadialGradient(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, new Stop[] {
                new Stop(0, Color.ORANGE),
                new Stop(0.2, Color.YELLOW),
                new Stop(0.5, Color.TRANSPARENT)
        });

        //I AM MODIFYING THIS VALUE
        int y = 500;

        Circle circleGradient = new Circle(200, y, 50);
        circleGradient.setFill(gradient);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(200 - 50, y - 50, 1000, 50/2);

        circleGradient.setClip(rect);

        canvasContainer.getChildren().addAll(circleGradient);

        mainPane.getChildren().add(canvasContainer);

        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image: y = 500]

[image: y = 575]

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @kleopatra there you go

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was trying to make a circle grow so it would fill a rectangle which was a small area of my Scene. The filling animation worked great but the maxHeight and maxWidth of your canvasContainer are ignored. In my case that ended up with the area growing and destroying everything nearby.

Solution : add the circle to the mainPane and not canvasContainer